# Click a link and stay on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-edge

I am trying to navigate to another HTML file without changing pages. Basically I got an emergency button, and once clicked, it should open an HTML file which pops up a box displaying 3 other buttons. This box also has an "X" to close the window, to close this HTML file and go back to the other.

Basically I want 2 html files to display at the same time. I am currently using adobe edge animate to do the process, however I am capable to use Javascript and HTML.

To give you an idea: It is similar to when visiting a website and a box pops up asking you if you want to subscribe to the news letter, or just keep searching.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. what i understand of your question. You want an html page on an html page. I suggest you could use JQuery popup screen. Visit this link. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/
If you want to call another html page without refreshing your page use Jquery .load(). http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#div_to_load_file_in" ).load( "path/to/your/file.html" );
```